# video call with ionic pwa

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

video call with ionic pwa

hello guys, i'm researching web rtc or video calling p2p.
I think about using ionic pwa for the ease of the framework and a requirement is that the customer does not need to install the app.

Any service or library suggestions that work well with ionic pwa to make this video call?

Comment: daily.co has an interesting api

Comment: https://openvidu.io/  this is chat system with calls